# Devexpress GridView in Searchloookupedit use of

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

As shown in the picture below, the product I am looking for from the `SearchLookupEdit` object I added on Gridview
I want to add them to the related columns on Gridview.

[image: pic]

Despite my research I have not found or used incorrect search words. I did not get it.

When `SearchLookupEdit` is selected, I want to insert the column named CARPAN in the Çarpan column on the Gridview.

The codes I use in the SearchLookupEdit object

```
DataTable Veri = new DataTable();
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["STOK"].ConnectionString);
conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter __Da = new SqlDataAdapter("select ID,AD,CARPAN from STOK_BIRIM order by ID desc", conn);
__Da.Fill(Veri);
repositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit1.DataSource = Veri;
repositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit1.DisplayMember = "AD";
repositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit1.ValueMember = "ID";
repositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit1View.Columns.Clear();
repositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit1View.Columns.AddVisible("AD", "BİRİM ADI");
repositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit1View.Columns.AddVisible("CARPAN", "CARPAN");     
repositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit1View.Columns["CARPAN"].Visible = false;
conn.Close();
```

Comment: The SearchLookUpEdit itself is a GridView and thus you can use standard GridView methods like GetRowCellValue to retrieve the value of a column cell within the SearchLookUpEdit's popup. You can then use the main GridView's SetRowCellValue to set the value of the "CARPAN" column. See: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q412836/searchlookupedit-how-to-get-value-from-selected-row-and-any-column